# Edit an existing cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to change just a single line in an installed cordova plugin.

> However, as the plugin is installed via `package.json`, any edit I do
>   on the source file does not get saved as the plugin is freshly
>   installed every time I make a new build of my app.

Is there some way to:

1. Copy-paste the whole plugin somewhere outside the `plugins` folder so I can edit without it getting overwritten.
2. Remove the plugin name from package.json and
3. Be able to reference the plugin inside my app so I can use the methods provided by the plugin.

Thank You.

Comment: If the plugin is hosted in GIT you can make a new branch, change the code, and then reference that version in your build.

Comment: Right. I have been testing it by copying the modified source files in git and referencing the url in package.json. It is working good :) Btw, Is there any other way to reference the plugin locally? Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Jamie, I only use plugins from GIT or from cordova.apache.org. I use Visual Studio & Dev Extreme for Cordova in this case I have nothing installed locally related to Corodva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the plugin and make the changes you want locally. Then you can add the plugin using `corodova plugin add /path/to/plugin/folder`.

Comment: Oh cool, so does it need to be done once or for every build? (can't test now -.-) Thanks

Comment: The path will be different for different devices...In prod this might be an isssue -.-

Comment: To answer your first question, it needs to be done only once for each project. Just like how you would add plugins normally.

Comment: To answer the second question, you could probably bundle it with your project files and refer to it using a **relative** path. Not sure, if this could work for your use case.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I could try some gulp task for adding the plugin into the project while running the build task. Thanks :)